# Aren't these two statements equivalent?

Tags: logic

I was watching a lecture about statements and implications and equivalences. Four statements were written and the goal was to find implications and equivalences between them. Two of the statements were:

$P : [x^2 = 4]\land[x \geq 0]$

and

$Q: [x = 2] \lor [x \gt 10]$

The teacher said that $P\Rightarrow Q$ but $Q \nRightarrow P$, why is this? $Q$ can be interpreted as $[x = 2]$ which very much implies $P$, so shouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: $P$ is just $x=2$ and $Q$ is $x=2 \lor x>10$. Note $p\Rightarrow p \lor q$ but not the other way round

Comment: With e.g. $x=11$ we have that $Q$ is True while $P$ is False. See truth-table for the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Definition_of_material_implication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x>10$ (e.g., $x=25$).

Then $Q$ is true but—since $x^2\neq 4$—$P$ false, i.e., $$Q\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies P.$$